# Are the mages from Three Shades of Night statted in the Chicago book too?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I read *Three Shades of Night* a very long time ago. Now I have learned that the vampire *and* werewolf characters are in *World of Darkness: Chicago*. Are the mages in there too? I tried to find the book or anything online but I can't seem to find anything even after searching.

[image: Three Shades of Night]

Comment: Glorianna was the self-taught mage, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Confirmed by the [wiki](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/World_of_Darkness:_Chicago) page (see the Special Thanks section).

Comment: For the record, this bounty's going to whatever answer actually tells us whether the mages in that book are statted (and if relevant, *where* they're statted). We've got a couple of answers effectively hoping they're in there somewhere, which is not quite far enough to make for a solid answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mages mentioned briefly in the Three Shades of Night, or rather in the third novel "Shadows and Mirrors", and given stats in a Chicago book:

- **Mimir**. In TSoN he is "the first chief legbreaker for the local Consilium", a scarecrow occasionally looming over the protagonists.
- **Eleagia**, mentioned once as someone controlling the Gold Coast through her 'bloodhounds'.
- **Airyaman** and **Protagoras** are mentioned as contacts, whose numbers Baihu gives Glorianna to search for the info on her father. It's stated that Airyaman has forgotten more about Chicago than most people ever know. She ended up having a very pleasant but fruitless conversation with them both off-screen.

And that is all. Most of the recurring characters, such as Glorianna, Mercedes, Tiaret, Baihu, Gwyn or Nuad are not in the Chicago book.

Comment: Congratulations, the bounty is yours. Thanks for carrying out your due diligence and investigating the mages specifically and reporting whether they're statted and which ones were.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure it's the same book, but looking at WoD:Chicago (same cover image); there is a mage section of the book starting on page 288.

1. Mage: Second Age of the Second City 288
2. Mage: Mages of the Second City 318
3. Mage: Unreal City 400

Comment: Do these feature stats for the mages the author's asking about?

Answer (score -2):

I believe so.

There is a section starting on page 318 of the *Chicago* book giving stats for several Mage characters:

- Theodore Walsh/Manipra
- Cynthia Walsh/Saena
- Fred Tazwell/Kukulkan
- Phillip Reidl/Mimir
- Martina Tessanopoulis/Cassandra
- Martin Tessanopoulis/Rebus
- Mischa Oscik/Aquamundi
- Padraig Abernathy/Taliesin
- Kaliki Sommers/Deathsong
- Ptarmigan Whitehall/Eleagia
- Nathan Perriman/Altus Vulcanis
- Lonny Davis/Llewellyn ap Pwyll
- Carlotta Belioni/Bella Lundi
- Etienne Dubois/L'Etranger
- Ramon Toulouse/The Chevalier
- Isabel Munoz/Madame Strega
- Sam Deland/The Red Jester
- Albert Hilliard/Maxwell Nightshade
- Shaunda Monroe/Princess Kundalini
- Benjamin Connelley/Triplex
- Patrice Waters/Southpaw
- Bradley Dodson/Grand Slam
- Anna Marie Chang/Pennant
- Glen Nelson/Laplace
- Edward Stacey/Zerb
- James Reszkie/Double Aught
- Juniper Kaye/Ethernet
- Christopher Yan/Player1
- Adrianne Elgar/Libra
- Adam Burnell/Zarathustra
- Marian Singer/Frigga
- Gordon Terrelle/Malkuth
- Leeland Price/Airyaman
- Shay McGuiness/Belisama
- Felicia Britt/Melpomene
- Stephen Glaebenstien/Webber Wormwood
- Sandra Rainer/Rose
- Michael Walsh/Protagoras
- Theseus Allen Peabody/Orion Aeternum
- Josephine Hall/Andromeda
- Roderigo del Torres/Impact
- Cecilia Collier/Pleiades
- Samuel Miller/Vayu
- Katherine Roth/Apas
- Gina Dandridge/Kore
- Nathan Victor Hamilton/Croseus
- Luz Concépción Maria Costas de Belaria/Lucretiana
- Carter Dean O’Shaughnessey/Argent
- Angelina Teresa Zircotti/Lira
- Roberta Denise Sangrale/Sofia Lex
- Ignatius Llywellyn/Professor Infinity
- Linda Chang/Magistra
- Frankie Mason/Flashback
- Peter Paul Sonderson/Father Lumen
- Deborah Abrahams/Serenitas
- Gabril Jasmin/Zaharana
- Anton Dilsek/Chernovkin
- Vanessa Walsh/The Crone
- Bridget Rose Murphy/Animalis
- Henry James Farragut/Baeldamor
- Delroy Joliet/Desinarim

So there are a LOT of them. I haven't read Three Shades of Night but it seems likely the characters are somewhere in that list.

Comment: Are you able to confirm if the characters are on that list somehow?